# how to import ionic app v3 code in android studio? How to run it?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have existing ionic v3 app code. I have tried to import it in android studio, while running, it shows me error: the Androidmenifest.xml file doesnot exist. How do I add the file?

Please, guide me.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly you want to do? why are you importing ionic app in android studio?

Comment: Have you added the Android platform to your project? In case you inherited the project and checked it out from GIT or whatever it needs to create all the Android project files first.

Comment: Hi, I am new to android, I have existing ionic app code in v3, I want to run the code in android studio. can you please help?